# How to manage a http request which requires lots of operation with database and other api?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need to make node js api with mysql with an request which does certain tasks.

An external API provides names of 100 user at once. I need to make multiple calls to get around 5000+ users. I need to add each user to database. Then each user will need to have it's information updated. The user needs to be assigned 0 value for in database so that I can modify these values later. This also numbers in 100's for each user.

In SQL, I use pooling to do each request. Doesn't this make it too slow? Each request needs to go to online database. Should I make query which does things for multiple users at same time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you build a single `INSERT` statement with 100 rows in it, it will run 10 times as fast as a 100 single-row `INSERTs`.

`LOAD DATA` may run even faster than that.

If you want to discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  (I don't know whether your "100's for each user" is 100 columns or 100 rows in another table, making it 500,000 rows.)

Comment: Say, Each User will be involved in 100 courses. And I have to store their grades,and other property. I just have to initialize these values as 0. So, it is 100's of rows for each student. so, yes, it's around 500,000 rows. And how do i manage if there is some error for some user? If there are some problems for 10 users but all others are ok.

Comment: Do you need to insert the 500K rows only once?  If so, why worry about the speed.  If you need to do it every hour, then we should discuss why the data needs to be changed so often.

Comment: Well, it should be done twice in a year.

Comment: @WanderingStudent - If you are replacing the entire table, build a new table and swap it into place.

Comment: No, I am not replacing the table. I am filling the table with new data.

Comment: @WanderingStudent - Let me phrase it a different way.  Are you replacing all the data in the table?

Comment: No, I am just adding records for the first time. I set the marks on all subject 0 so that I can retrieve all of them at once

Comment: @WanderingStudent - If this is a one-time task, it may work to simply ask for _all_ the records at once.  It may be slow and may take a lot of RAM, so be ready to increase time and space limits. when you discover them.